# Synchronize search pattern with opened tab from the user activity panel

Tags: feature-request, search

Currently opening any user profile automatically adds an "user:id" string into the topbar's search field. For [instance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio):

> [image: search for user related posts]

In case of switching between tabs on the [Activity panel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio?tab=topactivity).

It would be useful to reflect the current tab into the search criteria by modifying the query (when applicable). At least "Answers" and "Questions" tabs could be affected:

`user:162102 is:a` and `user:162102 is:q` respectively.